# Parsing JSON from a specific column in a CSV file

Tags: r, json, csv

I'm currently working with the TMDB_5000_movies.csv dataset on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata) and need some help with converting the columns that have JSON objects in them into a normalized dataframe.

For example, if a movie has multiple genres associated with it, I would want my dataset to be something along the lines of:

Budget    | Genre_1 | Genre_2   | etc.

100000000 | Action  | Adventure | ...

I would just base the number of genre_x columns based off of the movie that has the most genres associated with it. I've looked at packages like RJSON and JSONLITE and can't seem to get them to work with JSON that is contained within a CSV file, just a JSON itself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

read_csv("~/Downloads/tmdb_5000_credits.csv") %>%
  mutate(
    cast = map(cast, jsonlite::fromJSON),
    crew = map(crew, jsonlite::fromJSON)
  ) -> xdf
```

Make a long "cast" data frame:

```
map_df(1:nrow(xdf), ~{
  cast <- xdf$cast[[.x]]
  cast$movie_id <- xdf$movie_id[.x]
  cast$title <- xdf$title[.x]
  tbl_df(cast)
}) -> cast_df

cast_df
## # A tibble: 106,300 x 9
##    cast_id character   credit_id  gender    id name   order movie_id title
##      <int> <chr>       <chr>       <int> <int> <chr>  <int>    <int> <chr>
##  1     242 Jake Sully  5602a8a7c…      2 65731 Sam W…     0    19995 Avat…
##  2       3 Neytiri     52fe48009…      1  8691 Zoe S…     1    19995 Avat…
##  3      25 Dr. Grace … 52fe48009…      1 10205 Sigou…     2    19995 Avat…
##  4       4 Col. Quari… 52fe48009…      2 32747 Steph…     3    19995 Avat…
##  5       5 Trudy Chac… 52fe48009…      1 17647 Miche…     4    19995 Avat…
##  6       8 Selfridge   52fe48009…      2  1771 Giova…     5    19995 Avat…
##  7       7 Norm Spell… 52fe48009…      2 59231 Joel …     6    19995 Avat…
##  8       9 Moat        52fe48009…      1 30485 CCH P…     7    19995 Avat…
##  9      11 Eytukan     52fe48009…      2 15853 Wes S…     8    19995 Avat…
## 10      10 Tsu'Tey     52fe48009…      2 10964 Laz A…     9    19995 Avat…
## # ... with 106,290 more rows
```

Make a long "crew" data frame:

```
map_df(1:nrow(xdf), ~{
  crew <- xdf$crew[[.x]]
  crew$movie_id <- xdf$movie_id[.x]
  crew$title <- xdf$title[.x]
  tbl_df(crew)
}) -> crew_df

crew_df
## # A tibble: 129,609 x 8
##    credit_id     department gender    id job        name    movie_id title
##    <chr>         <chr>       <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <int> <chr>
##  1 52fe48009251… Editing         0  1721 Editor     Stephe…    19995 Avat…
##  2 539c47ecc3a3… Art             2   496 Productio… Rick C…    19995 Avat…
##  3 54491c89c3a3… Sound           0   900 Sound Des… Christ…    19995 Avat…
##  4 54491cb70e0a… Sound           0   900 Supervisi… Christ…    19995 Avat…
##  5 539c4a4cc3a3… Production      1  1262 Casting    Mali F…    19995 Avat…
##  6 5544ee3b9251… Sound           2  1729 Original … James …    19995 Avat…
##  7 52fe48009251… Directing       2  2710 Director   James …    19995 Avat…
##  8 52fe48009251… Writing         2  2710 Writer     James …    19995 Avat…
##  9 52fe48009251… Editing         2  2710 Editor     James …    19995 Avat…
## 10 52fe48009251… Production      2  2710 Producer   James …    19995 Avat…
## # ... with 129,599 more rows
```

Now, you can use any of the cadre of tidyverse and non-tidyverse methods to group, summarise, count, etc. then re-join into more compact structure.